# 3d object rotation issue in cocos3d

Tags: iphone, ios, blender, collada, cocos3d

I ve created a 3d object using **Blender** and exported in to collada form. And converted to pod file using **PVRGeoPod**.
I added the pod file to cocos3d project resources. Then altered the **hello-world project** by replacing pod name and node name.I didn't make any other change. When i run the project i can see the 3d object, but it is not rotating . I followed the exact steps in the tutorial of Brenwill. When i use other built-in pods i can see it rotates. Is there any other step that i should do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frnds, i found it by myself. I had problem in node name. So i gave custom node name

```
    [self addContentFromPODResourceFile: @"BlueBall.pod" withName:@"obj"];
    CC3MeshNode* ball = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed: @"obj"];
```

Now it does work. So whenever we have a confusion in node name we can give by custom.